# SSH Key manager

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centralized management system for SSH keys?](https://serverfault.com/questions/304286/centralized-management-system-for-ssh-keys)

I have multiple boxes and multiple employees. Is there a program or script that allows an admin to easily add or remove ssh keys? If an employee joins or leaves my company, it would be nice to run a command to allow or revoke their ssh key across multiple boxes.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/117072/a-system-for-distributing-ssh-public-keys

Comment: Have a look at userify.com for this sort of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it'd be easier and you'd have better luck finding a solution that removes the users from the user list, vs trying to remove ssh keys.

By removing the user, you're revoking that user's access to the machine.
Are you in a situation where this isn't possible?  If not, a script like the following can be used to easily remove users from all of your machines

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t user@host 'sudo userdel -r badusername'
ssh -t user@host2 'sudo userdel -r badusername'
```

The -r in userdel will remove the user's home directory, which means the key will be removed as well.