# Tool for managing ssh keys in a server cluster

Tags: ssh, debian, puppet, ssh-keys

I have couple of Debian servers and currently I am struggling around with adding manually ssh keys to  the server's `authorized_keys` files. Do you know an application which can do this in  a nice semi-automated way? Ideally with a nifty interface, where I can see which keys are used on which server etc.? 
I have just read in [this posting](https://serverfault.com/questions/13354/best-system-for-managing-ssh-keys) about [puppet](http://info.puppetlabs.com/download-puppet-open-source), but I need to evaluate it a bit. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: LDAP? LDAP. LDAP!

Comment: Oh, ok. Didn't know this. Is this the normal way of handling this?

Comment: and setting up and maintaining a LDAP server seems to my like more additional work. But thanks for pointing this out, so I can taking this also into account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centralized management system for SSH keys?](http://serverfault.com/questions/304286/centralized-management-system-for-ssh-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any change management system will do the trick; puppet and cfengine being the most used and either would do the job.

Personally, I favor puppet and the configuration to deploy SSH keys is built in and quite robust; it'd take only a few hours to deploy, get comfortable, and start using it for somthing as well-contained as ssh key management.  Here is some useful documentation on doing just that:

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Authorized_Keys_Patterns

As a bonus side effect, you'd then have a deployment system for other management tasks you could leverage.  :-)

Comment: To be fair, there is a learning curve. However, it's such a useful tool that soon you'll be looking for more things to manage. I started with simply managing ntpd.conf and sudoers.